# perl syntax to access the constant variable in cgi script

Tags: perl, bugzilla, template-toolkit

recently I was debugging a piece of code and found the following usage in the template tool kit usage in the template.

```
 #Constants.pm
 # Bugzilla version
 use constant BUGZILLA_VERSION => "4.0.11";


 #template file index.html.tmpl
 [% PROCESS global/header.html.tmpl
  header_addl_info = "version $constants.BUGZILLA_VERSION"
  style_urls = [ 'skins/standard/index.css' ] 
 %]

 #index.cgi
 use Bugzilla::Constants;
 .......

 print "buzilla version  :  $constants.BUGZILLA_VERSION <br/>";
```

When I am using the same syntax in the main cgi script , giving error 500

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 print "buzilla version  :  ".Bugzilla::Constants::BUGZILLA_VERSION." <br/>";
```

Answer (score 0):

'.' probably means something different in Template::Toolkit.

In Perl you just use BUGZILLA_VERSION:

```
$ perl -E 'use constant BUGZILLA_VERSION=>"4.0.11"; say BUGZILLA_VERSION' 
4.0.11
$
```